# TFS Branching and Work Item Tracking

Tags: tfs

I want to create a new stream in TFS just like we use to do in clear case or clear quest tool by IBM.  I believe we can achieve the same thing by creating a branch. I have been able to create branches but than when we create work items , we are not able to search work items for a particular branch . Work items are coming in root project only. Here is my structure
Root Project
 - Main Branch
 - New Branch

Am i doing it right way? Do i need to create a new project and branch there right under root level ? Like below
Root Project
 - Main Branch
New Project
 - New Branch

I hope i am able to clear what i want to achieve . Any TFS expert there?

Comment: You may describe the stream in clear case or clear quest tool.

Comment: Work items and branches have no relationship whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

TFS has work item tracking features designed to assist enterprise software development teams to manage their work and software defect tracking. Work Item is for a **team project**'s team, not for a single **project/branch** (team project and project are not same thing). You can specify Area and Iteration for a work item.

Regarding TFS branch, you would never branch a **team project**, but branch a **project**. Check: [Branch strategically](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-strategically). You can use branches to accomplish the following goals:

- Manage concurrent work by multiple teams on the same codebase
- Isolate risks that are introduced by different sets of changes to the
  codebase
- Take snapshots and then support subsequent isolated changes (for
  example, to create a release branch)